# Coded UI Test SetProper issues

Tags: c#-4.0, coded-ui-tests

```
public HtmlComboBox NetworkSelectBox
    {
        get
        {
            HtmlComboBox networkSelectBox = new HtmlComboBox(ConfigVMPage);
            networkSelectBox.SearchProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.Id] = "vnic";
            networkSelectBox.SearchProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.Name] = "vnic";
            networkSelectBox.FilterProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "style=\"WIDTH: auto\" id=vnic name=vnic  r";
            return networkSelectBox;
        }
    }
```

Above is the code I define an UI element and I want to set the property 
NetworkSelectBox.SelectedItem = "LabNetworkSwitch";

I've used this way on other elements and all success, but in this one i got the error message 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.ActionNotSupportedOnDisabledControlException: Cannot perform 'SetProperty of SelectedItem with value "LabNetwokrSwitch"' on the disabled or read-only control.

How can I change the control type?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to change the control type. I would suggest trying either waitforready() or find(). What is likely happening is when the control is initially found it is disabled, and find() will sync the actual control with the current networkSelectBox. WaitForReady() is probably the preferable method here though it will implicitly refresh the values of the combo box until it is available for input or the time out has expired.

I doubt you will run into this issue with HtmlComboBoxes but with a couple of WinComboBoxes I have had issues where they could not be set using SelectedItem or SelectedIndex. I ended up doing KeyBoardSendkeys(Combobox,"firstLetterOfItem") until the selected value was correct.